# how to create a half-box in html/css

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a div that has a left and top border with text in top line.  what I am trying to achieve is the following...

[html half box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzJAz.jpg)

I am able to get the top with the text using the following css or alternately a table but can't get it with the left border also.  any 'outside the box' thinkers?

```
.hr-sect {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
color: blue;
margin: 8px 0px;  
}
.hr-sect::before
{
    content: "";
width: 20px;
background: #000;
height: 1px;
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0px;
margin: 0px 8px;  
}
.hr-sect::after {
content: "";
width:100%;
background: #000;
height: 1px;
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0px;
margin: 0px 8px;  
}
```

CATEGORY

---

CATEGORY

---

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate that interrupted border line by using an absolutely placed div that has a non-transparent background, just make sure it matches the actual background color.

```css
.half-box {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}

.half-box > .title {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px">
</div>

<div class="half-box">
  some content
  <div class="title">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great.  seems so easy after seeing an answer! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set a positioning context on the outer box with `position: relative;`

For the border, use a pseudo `::before` element with `content: " ";` and give it a `position: absolute;` to take it out of the flow. Give it a top and left border.

For the heading, also use `position: absolute;` and move it up with `top: -20px` or whatever. Set the same background color as the outer box to mask the border.

Adjust your margins and paddings as needed.

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/matthewsmith_io/pen/RVYQqy